# BlazeDS deployment issue on Weblogic : Unable to create a parser to load messaging configuration

Tags: deployment, weblogic, blazeds

I am migrating a project from JBoss to Weblogic server.
The Java project uses BlazeDS in order to communicate with Flex front end.
It works fine on JBoss. However I have been struggling for a few days with the following exception.

```
flex.messaging.LocalizedException: Unable to create a parser to load messaging configuration.
```

The whole stack trace :

```
flex.messaging.LocalizedException: Unable to create a parser to load messaging configuration.
    at flex.messaging.config.FlexConfigurationManager.getMessagingConfiguration(FlexConfigurationManager.java:73)
    at flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet.init(MessageBrokerServlet.java:109)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:250)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:94)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:82)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:624)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:565)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1848)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1738)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2740)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1704)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:781)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:111)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:582)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:335)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

More details related to my configuration:

```
Java 1.7.0_21
blazeds-4.0.0.14931
weblogic 12c (12.1.1)
```

I had a look into the problematic class within the source code of BlazeDS.
[FlexConfigurationManager.getMessagingConfiguration()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.adobe.blazeds/blazeds-core/3.0.0.544/flex/messaging/config/FlexConfigurationManager.java#FlexConfigurationManager.getMessagingConfiguration%28flex.messaging.config.ServletConfig%29) crashes because the parser is null at line 70.
On line 68, it is calling [FlexConfigurationManager.getConfigurationParser()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.adobe.blazeds/blazeds-core/3.0.0.544/flex/messaging/config/FlexConfigurationManager.java#FlexConfigurationManager.getConfigurationParser%28flex.messaging.config.ServletConfig%29) which is unfortunately returning null.

Looks like this function is not able to find one of the following parsers...

```
flex.messaging.config.ApacheXPathServerConfigurationParser
flex.messaging.config.XPathServerConfigurationParser
```

Please note that even though the blazeds version of the web link seems to be 3.0.0.544, I have downloaded the latest source code of this file and it's nearly the same. So we can refer to it.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could give me some little hints...

Thanks in advance! ;)

Comment: Looks like the messaging-config.xml file is not parsable. Can you look it in IE and find out if the elements are ok?

Comment: The messaging-config.xml file is parsable. No errors when I look at it within IE or Eclipse. Thanks for proposing. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally ended up to make it work. We had to correct some configuration regarding our EJBs.

But most likely the main cause of the problem was the import of **gwt-dev** and its underlying **xml-apis** library!